# Trying to perform Wilcoxon matched pairs-test in R but get error message

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to test for significant difference between the medians of two matched samples:

1. female students and their chocolate ratings on a scale of 1-10 and
2. male students and their chocolate ratings on a scale of 1-10.

There are more female students than males - but the data is matched: the students are all in the same year and class.

I try to put this through R as follows:

```
wilcox.test(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact=True, paired=True, conf.int=True)
```

But I get:

```
Error in wilcox.test.default(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact = True,  : 
  object 'True' not found
```

Would someone kindly help me rectify this?

Comment: Try `T` instead of `True`. Also, unless I'm mistaken, you need the same number of samples in both series for `paired=T`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, using `T` is dangerous since (unlike `TRUE`) `T` is not a reserved word. You could for example define `T <- FALSE` and watch the world burn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `True` with `TRUE`. The error message is somewhat helpful: since `True` is not a reserved word, R is looking for an object `True` in your environment, and failing to find one. Hence `object 'True' not found`.

Comment: Is there a way I can tell R to ignore that the matched data is not the same length? wilcox.test(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact=TRUE, paired=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)
Error in wilcox.test.default(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact = TRUE,  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Comment: Looks like you are making progress by reading error messages! Next step is for you to start reading the documentations: run `?wilcox.test`. I think Lars already gave it away.

Comment: Ok. It works, but I get another warning message:  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact = TRUE,  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(dframeA$Chocolate, dframeB$Chocolate, exact = TRUE,  :
  cannot compute exact confidence intervals with ties  What does it mean? (I am very new to R).

Comment: Can you read the whole documentation and the warning message carefully and try to figure it out yourself?

Comment: I assume that the warning for 'ties' is coming up because I am comparing two samples of matched data that are not of the same length? R would only be able to compute exact results with data of exactly the same proportions?

Comment: No, you get warning about ties because your data contains duplicate values: you, R, Wilcoxon cannot unequivocally tell who likes chocolate better when two persons gave it the same rating (e.g. `5`)

Comment: Hi Flodel. Sorry, it has been ticked. :)